# OpenMPI doesn't kill other rank when one rank crashes

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I have some sample code:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // Initialize the MPI environment
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  // Find out rank, size
  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
  int world_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

  // We are assuming at least 2 processes for this task
  if (world_size < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "World size must be greater than 1 for %s\n", argv[0]);
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
  }

  int number;
  if (world_rank == 1) {
    number = -1;
    MPI_Send(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    raise(SIGSEGV);
  } else if (world_rank == 0) {
    MPI_Recv(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("Process 0 received number %d from process 1\n", number);
  }

  printf("rank %d finalize\n", world_rank);
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Rank 1 raises a signal to simulate crash. After the `raise()` rank 1 exits. But rank 0 stills prints `rank 0 finalize`.

Is there any way to know in rank 0 whether rank 1 crashes in this case? Is it possible to let `mpirun` kill rank 0 when rank 1 crashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note there is a race condition in your problem, and `mpirun` might have not enough time to notice task 1 crashed and kill task 0 before the message is printed.

You can force Open MPI to kill all tasks as soon as a crash is detected with the option below

```
mpirun -mca orte_abort_on_non_zero_status 1 ...
```